# No JSON Object could be decoded to missingkids website

Tags: python, json

I'm not sure why I am receiving this error. There is a decoder.py file in my python folder.

```
import requests
import json
import common

session = requests.Session()
uri = "http://www.missingkids.com"
json_srv_uri = uri + "/missingkids/servlet/JSONDataServlet"
search_uri = "?action=publicSearch"
child_detail_uri = "?action=childDetail"
session.get(json_srv_uri + search_uri + "&searchLang=en_US&search=new&subjToSearch=child&missState=CA&missCountry=US") #Change missState=All for all states

response = session.get(json_srv_uri + search_uri + "&searchLang=en_US&goToPage=1")
dct = json.loads(response.text)
pgs = int(dct["totalPages"])
print("found {} pages".format(pgs))
missing_persons = {}
```

Comment: Well that URL you're trying to open is a 404...

Comment: @Aran-Fey ironic ...

Answer (score 0):

The URL http://www.missingkids.com/missingkids/servlet/ returns a 404 Error. Thus, there is no JSON data for Requests to return. Fixing the URL so that it points to a valid destination will allow Requests to return page content.

To make a search for a missing child registered in that website's database, try this URL: http://www.missingkids.com/gethelpnow/search

Answer (score 0):

After every HTTP call you need to check the status code.

Example

```
import requests

r = requests.get('my_url')
# status code 'OK' is very popular and its numeric value is 200
# note that there are other status codes as well
if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    # do your thing
else:
   # we have a problem
```